# Session is automatically updating in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am facing a problem with session, I just get the data which is stored in session and I have updated the one of the item in that list, then I am verifying some condition. If the condition is satisfied then only it should update in the session.

But the problem is even though  I did not update in the session it is reflecting.

Below is the code I have written.

```
int index = (Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["rowIndex"]) - 1);
List<UserOrganizationMapping> updateUserOrgmapping = SessionHelper.GetSessionValue<List<UserOrganizationMapping>>("LstUserOrgMapping");

if (updateUserOrgmapping != null && updateUserOrgmapping.Count > 0)
{
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationName = context.Request["updateOrganizationName"];
    if (context.Request["updateOrganizationVal"] != "Select")
    {
        updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["updateOrganizationVal"]);
    }
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].ModifiedBy = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request["updateStartDate"]);
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request["updateEndDate"]);
    string error = VerifyOverlapping(updateUserOrgmapping);
    if (error != null)
    {
        GetSerializable(context, error);
    }
    else
    {
        updateUserOrgmapping = SessionHelper.GetSessionValue<List<UserOrganizationMapping>>("LstUserOrgMapping").ToList();
        SessionHelper.SetSessionValue("LstUserOrgMapping", updateUserOrgmapping);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is going to be much easier for you to debug than anyone else to solve. You need to stick a breakpoint on the line where the session value is being updated and work out why it's going through your logic to determine why it's getting there

Comment: i tried that when i am trying to update one of the item in the list by that time it self it is updating to session.

Comment: What do you know about pointers?

Comment: sorry i am not fully aware of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because what you get when you execute `SessionHelper.GetSessionValue` is *a reference to an object* so all subsequent manipulations to that object are reflected on where the actual data sits (heap). And this is also why the call to `SessionHelper.SetSessionValue` is redundant in your case.

You can fix the problem by copying the contents of a list you're getting from the session to a new object and perform your all your manipulations on that newly instantiated object instead:

```
var updateUserOrmapping = new List<UserOrganizationMapping>(
  SessionHelper.GetSessionValue<List<UserOrganizationMapping>>("LstUserOrgMapping")
);
```

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned, the above solution is still not sufficient and that is because although we have a new reference to a list itself, the list items that we copied *by reference* are still the ones that reside in the same place on the heap.

Basically, in your case you need to revert to the original state of the target object instance (`updateUserOrgmapping[index]`) when the error occurs. Here's an example (not very elegant but you get the point):

```
var originalOrganizationName = updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationName;
var originalOrganizationId = updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationId;
var originalModifiedBy = updateUserOrgmapping[index].ModifiedBy;
var originalStartDate = updateUserOrgmapping[index].StartDate;
var originalEndDate = updateUserOrgmapping[index].EndDate;

updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationName = context.Request["updateOrganizationName"];

// ...

string error = VerifyOverlapping(updateUserOrgmapping);
if (error != null)
{
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationName = originalOrganizationName;
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].OrganizationId = originalOrganizationId;
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].ModifiedBy = originalModifiedBy;
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].StartDate = originalStartDate;
    updateUserOrgmapping[index].EndDate = originalEndDate;

    GetSerializable(context, error);
}
```

The more elegant solution would probably be to make `UserOrganizationMapping` support deep copying of its state and then you could do something like this:

```
string VerifyOverlapping(IList<UserOrganizationMapping> mappings, UserOrganizationMapping modifiedMapping, int modifiedMappingIndex)
{
    string ret = null;

    // Keeping the reference to the original mapping.
    var originalMapping = mappings[modifiedMappingIndex];

    // Temporarily inserting the modified mapping for overlapping check.
    mappings[modifiedMappingIndex] = modifiedMapping;

    ret = VerifyOverlapping(mappings);

    // Getting the original value back on error.
    if (ret != null)
        mappings[modifiedMappingIndex] = originalMapping;

    return ret;
}

// ...    

int index = (Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["rowIndex"]) - 1);
var updateUserOrgmapping = SessionHelper.GetSessionValue<List<UserOrganizationMapping>>("LstUserOrgMapping");

if (updateUserOrgmapping != null && updateUserOrgmapping.Count > 0)
{
    var mapping = new UserOrganizationMapping(updateUserOrgmapping[index])
    {
        OrganizationName = context.Request["updateOrganizationName"],
        ModifiedBy = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString(),
        StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request["updateStartDate"]),
        EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request["updateEndDate"])  
    };

    if (context.Request["updateOrganizationVal"] != "Select")
        mapping.OrganizationId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["updateOrganizationVal"]); 

string error = VerifyOverlapping(updateUserOrgmapping, mapping, index);

if (error != null)
    GetSerializable(context, error);

// ...

public class UserOrganizationMapping
{
    public UserOrganizationMapping() { }
    public UserOrganizationMapping(UserOrganizationMapping copyFrom)
    {
        this.Id = copyFrom.Id;
        // Copy all field values
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.